# Good name for a colonial planet?

Tags: colonization, space-colonization

Specifically the first to be colonised by Humans (so it's more of a big deal for them) what names do you like from pre-existing media, or what name can you think up?

Comment: This looks like idea generation to me,... and as far as I love having input for names and stuff, and thus would be very interested in all the answers, I get the feeling this won't be left open long.... best of luck.

Otherwise, my personal favourite is Weywot (but it's already used for a moon). Generally I prefer (not unlike how they choose extra terrestrial bodies' name in reality) finding names from mythology etc...

Comment: Most science fiction tends to assume the first extrasolar colony would be settled by English-speaking people.

Comment: You could change the question to "How to come up with convincing and realistic names for a fictional planet"and edit the body to express the idea change. In that case you might look to different but related questions on naming schemes. A few search results are [How to name places that have multiple names](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/how-to-name-places-that-have-multiple-names) and [Are there techniques for creating alien or foreign names](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/are-there-techniques-for-creating-alien-or-foreign-sounding-names/3492#3492).

Comment: Welcome to the site Clyde, it takes some time to get used to the rules regarding how to ask a question around here but you'll figure it out..

Answer (score 1):

As a marketing stunt you could call it "Heaven" or "Paradise". Presumably it would be profitable for companies to take people there (otherwise why go?) so calling it something like that will make the journey more sought after. "Heaven" is also a very common and memorable word.

"Do you want to go to Heaven?"